# How to differentiate XML transaction in Liaison Delta and ECS

Tags: edi

Can you please some one help to with following scenario.

I have 2 XML messages(ORDERS, SHIPRTN) are placing into SFTP location, using ECS i am picking and translating with Delta, but How do i differentiate both ORDERS and SHIPRTN and call the respective Maps in Delta.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways to do this.  You can put a condition on the event rule if the data contains the batch , then call map "A".  if the data contains the data  then call map "B".

The other way is to set identity values in the model so that TPM can figure it out.